# Rotate object by 360 degrees with different Images in Ionic 5?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

i am creating an Ionic App to rotate an image of Car by 360 degrees. I want to rotate the object with different image files of same object (eg Car)

Here is the [Example of car](https://jsfiddle.net/qj8cfkab/2/) that I want to implement in my app.

i tried by using Gesture, loading different images on Gesture onMove.
But its not working properly.

Is there any cordova package is available? or any other way to achieve this?

**My Ionic info:**

```
Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.2.3

onSwipe(e) {
    let count = 0;
    let direction = '';
    if (e.deltaX > 0) {
      direction = 'R';
      count = Math.round(parseInt(e.deltaX) / 10);
    } else { // left
      // console.log('Left');
      direction = 'L';
      count = Math.round(parseInt(e.deltaX) / 10);
    }
    this.ref.detectChanges();
    this.imageChange(count, direction);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried using the sample from the JSFiddle and modify it to use gestureController. Maybe not the best solution. but it works

//your.html

```
<div (click)="createGesture()">
    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dewn0wy2s/image/upload/v1592668487/360/{{delta}}.png">
</div>
```

//your.component.ts

```
delta:number = 1;


constructor(
    private gestureCtrl: GestureController,
    private el: ElementRef
) { }

public createGesture() {
    const gesture = this.gestureCtrl.create({
      gestureName: 'rotateGesture',
      el: this.el.nativeElement,
      onStart: ($event) => {
        console.log("onStart")
      },
      onMove: ($event) => {
        if ($event.deltaX < 0) {
          this.delta = this.delta == 0? 51 : this.delta - 1
        } else {
          this.delta = this.delta == 51? 0 : this.delta + 1
        }
        console.log("onMove", this.delta, $event)
      },
      onEnd: ($event) => {
        console.log("onEnd", $event)
      },
    }, true);
    gesture.enable();
  }
```